# My container disappears when I make it 100% high

Tags: html, css, containers

I'm building this 15 page website so I really want to make my main container ( the light grey one ) be flexible in height.

When I select specific pixel height on my home page ( the only page so far ) everything is great but when I change it to 100% height, my container completely disappears. Is there anything I should do differently?

My link:

http://dariawdesign.com/acupuncture/StamfordAcupunctureHome.html

CSS for the container:

```
#maincontainer {
width: 1110px;
height: 3900px;
background-color: #E6E7E8;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -16px;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem works fine for me with the Google-inspector tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set your height to a pixel value, let it be `auto`. Then add `overflow: hidden` to your `#maincontainer` styles to expand the container to fit its floated children.

Comment: Thank you VLS, that did the trick. I also changed the height of my children containers ( main and sidebar ) to 100% to ensure everything is flexible.